# Validate unique email on update, ignoring self email. On Laravel 5

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.4 app, whenever I try to update a user with the email  unchanged, I get the error 'Email already in use', which makes sense since the edited user already has the email. Usually I deal with it simply by using something like this:

```
'email' => 'required|max:128|unique:users,email,'.$u->email,
```

However, this is not working on this particular app. I still get the same 'already in use' error.

The full validation rules object looks like this after php replaces the string:

```
$rules = [
  "name" => "required|max:64",
  "email" => "required|max:128|unique:users,email,user@admin.com",
  "role" => "required"
]
```

I can't find anything wrong with it. What could be causing the incorrect validation?
I'll add the whole update function validation process, in case it helps.

```
$u = User::find($id);

$input = $request->all();
$rules = [
  'name' => 'required|max:64',
  'email' => 'required|max:128|unique:users,email,'.$u->email,
  'role' => 'required'
];
$messages = [
  'email.required' => 'El Email es obligatorio',
  'email.max' => 'El Email no debe exceder los 128 caracteres',
  'email.unique' => 'Ya existe un usuario con este Email',
  'name.required' => 'El nombre es obligatorio',
  'name.max' => 'El Email no debe exceder los 64 caracteres',
  'role.required' => 'El Rol es obligatorio',
];
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
if ( $validator->fails() ) {
  return redirect('users/'.$id.'/edit')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
} else {
    // update user
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `$u->email` isn't quite right for the `unique` rule. The signature is

```
unique:{table},{column},{value_to_ignore},{column_to_ignore}
```

So, with your rule set as

```
unique:users,email,'.$u->email
```

It's trying to find a user with an `id` of `$u->email`, due to the default `column_to_ignore` being set to `id` (or whatever the primary key of your `users` table is)

To fix this, simply change your `unique` rule as below:

```
$u = User::find($id);
$rules = [
    "email" => "required|email|max:128|unique:users,email,".$u->id.",id", 
    ...
];
```

*Note: You can omit the `",id"` from the rule if you like. As said, this will default to the primary key of your `users` table. If you changed it from `id`, then you will need to specify it.*

With the rule adjusted as above, this will signify that when editing this User and determining unique entries, ignore the value in the `email` column where `users.id = $u->id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $current_user  = Users::where('access_token', $request->access_token)->first();

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
        'name'            => 'required|max:255',
        "email"           => "required|email|max:100|unique:users,email,".$current_user->id.",id",  
    ]);
```