# Laravel different validation doesn't work with strings containing numbers

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to validate a value that I got from a certain form. The value type is text. I want it to match a specific username from the database from the `users` table, but also to not match the current user's username.

To achieve that, I used the following validation rules:

```
'username' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    'exists:App\User,username',
    'different:' . auth()->user()->username
]
```

What I've discovered is that whenever the `auth()->user()->username` value includes a digit, it passes the validation even if `request()->username = auth()->user()->username`. Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `unique` like -

Considering `id` is your user's id.

`'username' => 'required|string|unique:username,id,'.auth()->user()->username,`

This will check if username is unique or not except this userId.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work for me. I want it to refer to an existing record in the database, which `unique` doesn't support.

Comment: ```unique``` will consider in exsting records as well. refer - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

Comment: Even if that was true, this validation doesn't allow existing usernames to be entered.

Comment: Though I changed my formula to something that works for my case:
`'username' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:users,username,'.auth()->user()->username]`

Comment: Chekout this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335632/validate-unique-email-on-update-ignoring-self-email-on-laravel-5

Comment: Just to make it clear, I want it to work like this does:
`'username' => ['required', 'string', 'exists:App\User,username']`
but to error out if `request()->username = auth()->user()->username`.

Comment: What do you mean? I am not getting you. Can your elaborate, please?

Comment: I would like to create a transaction between two users. The current user will be sending the money and the specified one will be receiving them. I don't want the user to send money to himself (obviously), but I also don't want to send money to someone who doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: The `username` field provides the recipient's username.

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121417/laravel-validation-exists-with-additional-column-condition-custom-validation

Comment: I was actually looking for something else, I already posted an answer to my own question so you can see what I really meant. Thanks for help anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this issue was creating own `Rule::exists` validation, which is shown below:

```
'username' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('username', '<>', auth()->user()->username);
    })
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem as follows.

```
$request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email','unique:users,email,'.Auth::id()],
            'phone' => ['required', 'unique:users,phone,'.Auth::id()],
        ]);
```